# How can I use powershell command in console app

Tags: c#, powershell, console

I did a console app to launch powershell commands.

I follow this code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18409/Asynchronously-Execute-PowerShell-Scripts-from-C and adapted to a command programe.

The problem comes with ISynchronizeInvoke that need mandatory a form app.
How can I use to replace ISynchronizeInvoke??

I add to the code

```
private ISynchronizeInvoke invoker ;

public ISynchronizeInvoke Invoker 
//Property to get or set the object to Sync up against.
{
    get { return this.invoker; }
    set { this.invoker = value; }
}
```

but like is a console app, invoker is null.

Thanks

Comment: Is it necessary for you to execute powershell commands asynchronously?

Comment: synchronously and asynchronously.
I going to release the same commands with a lot of powershell sentences, a lot of times, each command asynchronously by threads, and inside a command synchronuously.